# Shorten the Code for CSS

Tags: css

how to shorten this code of `CSS`? when it is in a mobile view it will hide some of the columns of the table. And my table has 137 columns and i only want to view only 5 columns.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        #data th:nth-child(2),
        #data td:nth-child(2),
        #data th:nth-child(3),
        #data td:nth-child(3),
        #data th:nth-child(5),
        #data td:nth-child(5),
        #data th:nth-child(6),
        #data td:nth-child(6),
        #data th:nth-child(7),
        #data td:nth-child(7),
        #data th:nth-child(8),
        #data td:nth-child(8),
        #data th:nth-child(9),
        #data td:nth-child(9),
        #data th:nth-child(10),
        #data td:nth-child(10),
        #data th:nth-child(11),
        #data td:nth-child(11),
        #data th:nth-child(12),
        #data td:nth-child(12) {display:none;}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide all and show again 13th and next.

```
#data tr > * {display: none}
#data tr > *:nth-child(12) ~ * {display: table-cell}
```

`tr > *` takes both, `td` and `th`, no other children can be in `tr`. And 13th and others (`:nth-child(12) ~ *`) are set to default `table-cell` value.

Comment: thank you sir. but i tried it already that ill hide all and then when i use `display:block` its table displays like this [click here to view screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/8AG93S6.png)

Comment: @RigelKentCarbonel: not `display: block`, but `table-cell`. I've updated immediately when I sent it, but you saw that. Sorry, `table-cell` is correct.

Comment: @RigelKentCarbonel Why is this the answer? This is not what you asked in your question.

Answer (score 3):

The code below will select every :nth-child after the 5th one..

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        #data th:nth-child(n+5){
           display:none;
        }
  }
```

Also,l here is a great article on the nth-child selector: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class on all the columns that are non-mobile columns and then use the class selector to hide them all instead of the nth-child selector.

Comment: But I'm using a gridview sir? @Nashibukasan

Comment: This can easily be done with gridview, but not the correct way. See my answer.

Comment: Depending on what sort of gridview you are using, you should still be able to add a class attribute. I prefer this method as it logically labels columns that are for mobile instead of selecting columns via their positioning. The n-child method is less messy though, so perhaps easier in your circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, here is a quick solution, if you like it you can read about `n-child` selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)

```css
ul li:nth-child(-n+10) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li
    ><li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
  <li> testing  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what's the meaning of -n+10 sir?

Comment: @RigelKentCarbonel it means it will match every child from the top up until top +10;